# Do the Query and GqlQuery operations cache their results automatically?

Tags: google-app-engine, caching

When performing a query in AppEngine, you can use a `Query` or `GqlQuery` object to fetch data from the datastore. I was wondering if these objects cache their result sets, or if they fetch the data every time. For example, in the case that you need to loop over the results multiple times:

```
query = GqlQuery('SELECT * '
                 'FROM User '
                 'WHERE favorite_color = :1',
                 'pink')

for user in query:
    # perform setup ...

# do some intermediary step ...

for user in query:
    # final step ...
```

In the loops, the query object automatically calls `.run()` and returns an iterable, but is it hitting the actual database every time, or does it cache it, meaning that the second `for` loop would be a much faster operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Results aren't cached because they could change at any time, and there's no practical way to invalidate all the result sets that could contain a modified result. If all you want to do is do the steps in your sample code without executing the query twice, simply call `.fetch()` on the query object to get a list of objects, and iterate over that instead of the query itself.

Answer (score 0):

No, they don't. You have to do the caching yourself. Use memcache or one of the off the shelf wrappers around the datastore that does this for you.